# Django QuerySet - How to "disable" previous filtered value

Tags: django, model, filter, django-queryset

I have a base model class that creates history of an object each time the objects has been changed. The model has field named 'is_history'. The idea is that a new instance of the model is created with the old data each time the model has been changed by someone. The new model with the old data has 'is_history=True' because becomes history object.
In the default admin changelist I do not want to see the history objects. I do not want to see them anywhere by default. Thats why i created new manager that overwrites the default get_query_set() and adds 'is_history=False'.

```
def get_query_set(self):
    qs = super(ModelHistoryManager, self).get_query_set()
    return qs.filter(is_history=False)
```

But I also should be able to show the history objects in the changelist view rarely, using admin filter for example.

My question is: I have a queryset that has already filtered this value. But in the admin's filter I get the filtered queryset from the base manager and  I want to change this filter from is_history=False to is_history=True, or to remove the filter for 'is_history' if the user wants to show all records - both history and original records.

Any idea?

Comment: why don't you create two managers? for admin and non-admin?

Comment: How to filter the values in the admin on that way? The admin uses the standard objects manager. All this things happen in the context of the admin, not in custom views.

Comment: yeah, I get it. why not to use custom manger in custom views? or alternatively you can create a abstract model and use it in admin. extend it from the original one and override the default manager in it.

Comment: The custom manager with custom admin does not solve the problem. The admin will apply the 'is_history=False' filter from the manager, but later in the admin's filter I have to change this value..sooo I have to change the queryset again..a custom admin is not the solution i think :/

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused. you can override `queryset` method in ModelAdmin and return "pure" queryset for admin things.

Comment: I can, but i have to apply again all filters passed in the admin's changelist. I will check how to handle this.

Comment: no no, filters applied in ChangeList (line 298 contrib/admin/views/main.py) and they are built on top of `self.root_query_set`. when `self.root_query_set = model_admin.queryset(request)` where `model_admin` is actually instance of ModelAdmin I propose to override method `queryset`

Comment: Yes, but the decision which manager to be used is taken later in an admin filter class that checks if the user wants to show the history objects or not :) All admin's filters are collected by the changelist.

Comment: ah, so probably you have to tweak ChangeList then. even tho it is pretty much doable :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote the django Docs about [Custom Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets):

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager
>   Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model)
>   has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a
>   class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including
>   dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a
>   result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default
>   manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_query_set()
>   results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

So, you should do something like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    custom_manager = MyCustomManager() # This has overrided the get_query_set method
```

Of course, you should use `custom_manager` instead of `objects` if you want the filtered model instances

Comment: I know about this. But i have to change the result depending on filtered value. If the user has applied filter by this field, I have to create a new queryset from the second manager, to apply all filters  from the admin and return the queryset. If the user has not applied any filter, the default queryset must be return. These filter choices are managed in the admin's filter, no in the get_query_set().

Answer (score 0):

You can *hack it*, but let me warn you that, this is **a very bad idea** and touches internals not meant to be touched by users. But if you insist, this would do the trick:

```
from django.db.models.sql.where import WhereNode
qs.query.where = WhereNode()
```